# Visual Studio Code working with Python with PYTHONPATH and separate source and tests folders

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest, pythonpath

Given a project structure:

```
* project
  * src
    * my_package
      * __init__.py
      * code_file.py
  * tests
    * __init__.py
    * my_package
      * __init__.py
      * code_file_test.py
```

How do I get Visual Studio code to identify that src is the root for code files so this will work for all of these:

1. intellisense
2. running
3. discovering and running tests

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ so can right click the `src` folder and mark it as the source root. There is no simple solution in VSC, however, this workaround could help.

Under the project root add the following file:

`.vscode/settings.json`

```
* project
  * .vscode
    * settings.json
```

with the following content:

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/", "${workspaceFolder}/"],
    "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["${workspaceFolder}/src/", "${workspaceFolder}/"],
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}\\src;${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/src:${workspaceFolder}"
    },
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-t", ".",
        "-s", "./tests",
        "-p", "*test.py"
    ],
    "pythonTestExplorer.testFramework": "unittest",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

(The two last parameters assume you are using the `unittest` python framework, change if using another one.)

If this doesn't work, make sure you have the following extensions installed:

```
ms-python.python
ms-python.vscode-pylance
ms-vscode.test-adapter-converter
hbenl.vscode-test-explorer
littlefoxteam.vscode-python-test-adapter
```

If the above doesn't work, try restarting VSC, if that doesn't work, you may have to alter imports like this...

In `src` code:

```
# Instead of: from my_package.different_file import AnotherClass
# use:
from .different_file import AnotherClass

# Instead of: from my_other_package.different_file import AnotherClass
# use:
from ..my_other_package.different_file import AnotherClass
```

In `tests` code:

```
try:
    from my_package.my_file1 import MyClass1
    from my_package.my_file2 import MyClass2
except ImportError:
    from src.my_package.my_file1 import MyClass1
    from src.my_package.my_file2 import MyClass2
    pass
```

Comment: Hi Danny Varod, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT this mostly works, hoping for a better solution. I've edited the answer accordingly. I'm pretty sure the only way to completely support this is add support to VSC itself.

Comment: If you try to open `src` directly as [a workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_how-do-i-open-a-vs-code-workspace) does that meet your need?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT, no. The repo contains `src` and `tests` and `requirements.txt` and other files, I need the entire repo. In IntelliJ and PyCharm this works via `Mark directory as Sources root`. Which sets PYTHONPATH env variable as I did above for the terminal for everything running in that instance of IJ/PY including terminal, intellisense, tests, run, debug etc. This is the main reason I prefer IJ over VSC despite VSC's many options.